# Windows: Screen turns off and on again every time I plug in my power cord

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display, power-supply, battery

I am having a lenovo X1 running window 10. As mentioned in the title, every time when I plug in my power cord or remove it, my laptop monitor turns off and on. I tried having the power and brightness settings same for when its connected to power and on battery but it still didn't help.

Comment: Could be a battery near end-of-life. How long does it run on battery?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, The laptop is brand new. The battery stays up for more than 8 hours.

Comment: If that is a defect in a brand new machine, return it.

Comment: Does this happen before Windows starts? i.e. in BIOS/UEFI? What if you run another OS? (like live USB Linux).

Comment: Is your video card driver up to date?

Comment: Has it even been established this isn't snafu? This could be how the monitor is designed to work for this laptop.

Comment: @wrecclesham, yes it is.

Comment: @CliffArmstrong, its a 2K laptop and if its how it is designed to work, I am deeply disappointed.

Comment: Why? What difference does it make? My left monitor goes off and back on when I switch my surround amp off or on (the hdmi for that monitor goes through the amp), But it's back on in under a second and affects nothing. And it is, in fact, how that amp is designed to work... are you saying I should be deeply disappointing with my $600 surround amp despite it being a complete non-issue? That makes no sense.

Comment: Try to lower the monitor's refresh rate: Right-click the desktop > Display Settings > Advanced Display Settings > Display Adapter Properties > Monitor > Screen Refresh Rate. Set it to 50 Hertz (if available).

Comment: Laptops seamlessly transfer from AC to battery, and vice versa⁠—that's why they don't crash when you connect or remove the charge cable. The power to the laptop itself is consistent (even now, because the OP's CPU and RAM doesn't actually lose power while the screen is black.) This can't be normal. I think it's a software, not hardware issue. harrymc might have nailed it with the refresh rate tip. @CliffArmstrong I see your point but you would *expect* the HDMI output from an audio amp to introduce hiccups like that. You wouldn't expect a laptop to be confused by its *own* power supply!

Comment: As a rule, you are correct that laptops switch seamlessly. But you are wrong when you say this *can't* be normal for this laptop. And the laptop isn't going to crash from the monitor switching off and on. What is expected doesn't determine if something needs fixing. What determines if something needs fixing is *whether it is causing or is likely to cause problems*. If this is the way this laptop is designed to work and it's not causing problems... then there's nothing to fix no matter how many other laptops don't do this. And trying will be an exercise in pointless frustration.

Comment: Hence why I asked if anyone has actually checked to see if that's not how this laptop is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some laptops lower the monitor's refresh rate when going on battery, to increase
it again when main power is restored.
This may cause a short flicker.

If this flicker is bothersome, you may lower the refresh rate when on power to be
the same as when on battery, to avoid the change.

I have seen laptops that reduced the refresh rate from 60 Herz to 50 Herz
on battery. If yours is one of them, connect the power cord and then lower the
refresh rate to 50 Herz. This is done in:

*Right-click the desktop > Display Settings > Advanced display Settings > Display adapter properties > Monitor tab > Screen refresh rate*.

Set Screen refresh rate to 50 Hertz (if available) or lower.